# free resolution of $\mathbb{Z}$ as an $\mathbb{Z}[x]/(x^n-1)$-module

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, free-modules

As the tittle says, I am having a bad time thinking on the construction of a free resolution of $\mathbb{Z}$ as an $(\mathbb{Z}[x]/(x^n-1))$-module.

I know that I should give an exact sequence of the form (if $R= \mathbb{Z}[x]/(x^n-1)$):

$... \longrightarrow R^{I_n} \longrightarrow ...\longrightarrow R^{I_1} \longrightarrow R^{I_0} \longrightarrow \mathbb{Z} \longrightarrow 0$

being

$d_i : R^{I_i} \longrightarrow R^{I_{i-1}}$ for $i \ge 1 $

$d_0: R^{I_0} \longrightarrow \mathbb{Z}$

$e: \mathbb{Z} \longrightarrow 0$.

and $R^{I_i}$ being free $R$-modules.

Moreover they should satisfy the exact sequence condition: $Im(d_i)=Ker(d_{i-1})$.

I began thinking on the first application $d_0: R^{I_0} \longrightarrow \mathbb{Z}$. But I had some troubles finding it. I thought sending

$a_0 + a_1 \bar{x} + a_2 \bar{x}^2+...+a_{n-1} \bar{x}^{n-1} \mapsto a_0$

because I need $Im(d_0)=Ker(e) = \mathbb{Z}$. But it gets harder to find $d_1$.

Then I thought:

$a_0 + a_1 \bar{x} + a_2 \bar{x}^2+...+a_{n-1} \bar{x}^{n-1} \mapsto \sum a_i$

but again it gets hard.

Any hint/help?

**EDIT:** I chose $R^{I_0}$ to be $R$.

Comment: Your second guess is the right one. However, it might be better to say that $d_0$ sends $f(\overline{x})$ to $f(1)$. What would then be the kernel of $d_1$?

Comment: Do you mean $d_0$ sends $f(\bar{x})$ to $f(1)$?

Comment: Correct, sorry. I have editted the mistake

Comment: Agree with Greg. Basically this comes from how do you view $\Bbb{Z}$ as an $R$-module. Because $x^n=1$ in $R$, the monomial $x^n$ must act as the identity. This places severe restrictions on how $x$ can act on $\Bbb{Z}$. If $n$ is even, then $x$ can act via either $+1$ or $-1$, but if $n$ is odd, then you **must** have $x\cdot m=m$ for all $m\in\Bbb{Z}$. Because $d_0$ must be a homomorphism of $R$-modules, it follows that either $x^i\mapsto d_0(1)$ or $x^i\mapsto (-1)^id_0(1)$. The latter case corresponding to the possibility that $n$ is even, and $x\cdot m=-m$ for all $m\in\Bbb{Z}$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider the following sequence of $R$-modules:

$$ \ldots \longrightarrow R \longrightarrow R  \longrightarrow R \longrightarrow \mathbb{Z} \rightarrow 0 . $$
We denote by $d_i$ the usual map.
We define $d_0: R \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}: f(\overline{x}) \rightarrow f(1).$
Then, the kernel of $d_0$ corresponds to the polynomials in $R$ such that $f(1) = 0$.
Consider now $d_1: R \rightarrow R: g(\overline{x})\rightarrow (\overline{x-1})g(\overline{x}). $

Notice that, per construction, the image of $d_1$ is the kernel of $d_0$.  The kernel of $d_1$ is the set of functions such that $g(\overline{x})(\overline{x-1})=0$.
Try to complete the sequence, using the fact that $(1+x+\ldots + x^{n-1})(x-1) = x^n-1.$

Comment: As a sidenote: $\mathbb{Z}$ can be regarded as an $R$-module by letting $x$ act as $1$ on $\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Oh yeah! The resolution continues periodically (assuming $x$ acts as the identity).

Comment: Exactly, @JyrkiLahtonen !

Comment: Can I choose $R^{I_i}$ to be equal for different $i$? $d_i$ can be equal for some $i$? And what do you mean by the usual map? Thank you very much.

Comment: Yes, you can. As long as the sequence stays exact!

Comment: And by the usual map, I just meant that $d_i$ is the map from $R^{I_i} \rightarrow R^{I_{i-1}}$.

Comment: I am sorry but what do you mean by complete the sequence? $d_i$ should be the same as the $d_1$ you have defined above, right?

Comment: No, not every $d_i$ is equal to $d_1$. However, the $d_1$ will reappear in the resolution later on. Using the hint, you should be able to find $d_2$, and from there, try to continue.

Comment: I do not know if I am correct. I will write my thoughts on here and may you can correct me. I can decide $d_2: R \longrightarrow R$ to send $\alpha(\bar{x})$ to $\alpha(1)$. Then its image would concide with the kernel of $d_1$ and then define $d_3$ as $d_1$ and $d_4$ as $d_2$ and so on. Would that be correct?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/87428/discussion-between-idriskameni-and-greg).